# Syntax Error or default_popup - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am learning how to build Chrome extensions and I am getting this error message..even though the video I am watching uses the same code.

Here is my JSON file

```
{

"name": "My Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "This is a short description for our Chrome Extension.",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon16.png"
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}

}
```

Comment: Invalid json, put comma after default_icon.Ex; "default_icon": "icon16.png","default_popup": "popup.html"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read the documentation on how to properly format a code snippet. You will make the example easier to read and show that you put some effort.

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae Don't modify the question with corrected syntax, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JoshLee sorry for that, I forgot to delete the changes which i have made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below valid `json`

```
{
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This is a short description for our Chrome Extension.",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon16.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! What did you change if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: In browser_action object, you have to give comma after "default_icon": "icon16.png"